# Unable to generate Oauth2 access token on WSO2 Identity server when using CloudFoundry-UAA as the identity provider

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, cloudfoundry-uaa, wso2-identity-server

I have followed the steps mentioned in https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Try+Authorization+Code+Grant. In addition to the steps, I have configured Cloudfoundry-UAA as the identity provider and generate access token using an Cloudfoundry user. I am able to generate the Authorization code by following the steps mentioned in the above link. But, when i use the Authorization code to generate an access token, I am getting the following error
***invalid_grant, Provided Authorization Grant is invalid***

Any inputs on this is highly appreciated. Need help on how to debug this issue.
UAA API's can be found [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/api/uaa/#overview)

Comment: appreciate if you could provide some more details. Things like the complete error printed on the IS logs, requests sent etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
Sample request for getting access token :
'POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9443
Authorization: Basic WUhvYUpJcE5NbHB3UDdPS2lUN2d0Ym5nZlkwYTpEcUFERWltUnRfYmRvUjBvZFRCZkVxUkdlaWNh
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: ef59097f-f668-5681-794c-9473d0ae1fcc

code=97SV6OVa2a&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret=DqADEimRt_bdoR0odTBfEqRGeica&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fplayground2%2Foauth2client&client_id=YHoaJIpNMlpwP7OKiT7gtbngfY0a'

Comment: Sample request once again
POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9443
Authorization: Basic WUhvYUpJcE5NbHB3UDdPS2lUN2d0Ym5nZlkwYTpEcUFERWltUnRfYmRvUjBvZFRCZkVxUkdlaWNh
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: ef59097f-f668-5681-794c-9473d0ae1fcc

code=97SV6OVa2a&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret=DqADEimRt_bdoR0odTBfEqRGeica&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fplayground2%2Foauth2client&client_id=YHoaJIpNMlpwP7OKiT7gtbngfY0a

Comment: By Logs do you mean the http_access_logs. I cant find any error messages there,  can you please provide me the path of the log file ?